# Why is this output happening?

Tags: c

This is an assignment for one of my classes, that requires you to convert from one base to another while ignoring all the comment lines (starting with '@') from an input file by command line.

I wrote a C program but when I ran it with the input file, it seems to covert the first number correctly but would just print the first result with increased line number for almost indefintely. I just have no clue on how to fix the code any suggestions would help.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void data_line(char line[])
{
  int input_base;
  char value[35];
  int output_base;

  sscanf(line, "%d %s %d", & input_base, value, & output_base);

  int n = strlen(value);

  int decimal = 0;

  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    if (value[i] >= '0' && value[i] <= '9')
    {
      decimal += pow(input_base, n - i - 1) * (value[i] - '0');
    }
    else
    {
      value[i] = tolower(value[i]);
      decimal += pow(input_base, n - i - 1) * (value[i] - 'a' + 10);
    }
  }

  char output[35];

  int k = 0;

  while (decimal > 0)
  {
    int rem = decimal % output_base;

    if (rem >= 10)
      output[k] = ('A' + rem - 10);
    else
      output[k] = ('0' + rem);

    k++;
    decimal = decimal / output_base;
  }

  if (k == 0)
  {
    printf("0\n");
  } else
  {
    for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      printf("%c", output[i]);

    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char line[100];
  int line_no = 1;

  while (fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]%*c", line) != EOF)
  {
    if (line[0] >= '0' && line[0] <= '9')
    {
      printf("%d: ", line_no);
      data_line(line);
    }

    line_no++;
  }

  fclose(fp);

}
```

my input.txt samples:

```
@ a first example
8 70 4

2 011100 16
7 0 21
11 3A 10
```

my output:

```
2: 320
3: 320
4: 320
5: 320
6: 320
7: 320
8: 320
9: 320
10: 320
11: 320
12: 320
13: 320
14: 320
15: 320
16: 320
17: 320
18: 320
19: 320
20: 320
...
...
...
```

```
expected output:
2: 320
4: 1C
5: 0
6: 43
```

Comment: Read the documentation of `fscanf`, specifically the [section about return codes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html#RETURN_VALUE). It may return 0 to indicate that it converted 0 items, or a number less than the expected number. You should check for the expected number of converted items. The same applies to `sscanf`.

Comment: A good idea is to use a _debugger_ to find problems. Put your code in [this one](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), for example

Comment: Also, use `printf()` to print intermediate values, to be sure all steps are behaving as expected.

Comment: .. and have a look at `fgets()`. I woud rather use that than `fscanf()` in tihs case

Comment: If you read the input as strings, `strtol` basically does all the work for you from there.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the comments always test the return codes from `scanf()` family functions. It is not an error for these functions to read nothing. They are **scan**ners for **f**ormatted input, as says their names.
Also you may find easier to consume the file lines using `fgets()`

#### Example

The loop below reads the file, prints out the comment lines for testing and maybe easier to read.

```
    while (NULL != (p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)))
    {
        switch (line[0])
        {
            case '@':
                printf("%s\n", line);
                break;
            case '\n':  // blank
                break;
            default:
                data_line(line);
                break;
        }
    }
```

### A complete test with a few changes

#### `input.txt`

```
@ a first example
8 70 4

2 011100 16
7 0 21
11 3A 10
@ end of input
```

#### output

```
@ a first example

  input base: 8  output base: 4
  value is "70"
  output value is 320

  input base: 2  output base: 16
  value is "011100"
  output value is 1C

  input base: 7  output base: 21
  value is "0"
  output value is 0

  input base: 11  output base: 10
  value is "3a"
  output value is 43

@ end of input
```

Using your code

- I changed the main loop to use `fgets()`
- added `input.txt` as the default file name
- changed `data_line()` to return `int` so you can test for lines that are not comments but are ill-formed
- grouped the output of `data_line()` to make it easier to read and change
- added some casts to avoid the many compiler warnings

#### complete code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int data_line(const char* line)
{
    int  input_base;
    char value[35];
    int  output_base;

    int res = sscanf(
        line, "%d %s %d", &input_base, value, &output_base);
    if (res != 3) return -1;

    size_t n       = strlen(value);
    int    decimal = 0;

    for (int i = (int)n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (value[i] >= '0' && value[i] <= '9')
        {
            decimal += (int)pow(
                           (double)input_base,
                           (double)(n - i - 1)) *
                       (value[i] - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            value[i] = tolower(value[i]);
            decimal += (int)pow(
                           (double)input_base,
                           (double)(n - i - 1)) *
                       (value[i] - 'a' + 10);
        }
    }

    char output[35] = {0};
    int  k          = 0;

    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        int rem = decimal % output_base;

        if (rem >= 10)
            output[k] = ('A' + rem - 10);
        else
            output[k] = ('0' + rem);

        k++;
        decimal = decimal / output_base;
    }
    // all output here
    printf(
        "  input base: %d  output base: %d\n  value is "
        "\"%s\"\n  output value is ",
        input_base, output_base, value);
    if (k == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
        for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            printf("%c", output[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* dflt = "input.txt";
    FILE*       fp   = NULL;
    if (argc < 2)
        fp = fopen(dflt, "r");
    else
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;

    char  line[100];
    int   line_no = 0;
    char* p       = NULL;

    while (NULL != (p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)))
    {
        switch (line[0])
        {
            case '@':
                printf("%s\n", line);
                break;
            case '\n':  // blank
                break;
            default:
                data_line(line);
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```